# wordpress custom post type sub page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have `portfolio` post type. For templating, i use `archive-portfolio.php`, and for the detail, use the `single-portfolio.php`

For menu management i created pages. First, i created portfolio page. It results slug like this: *site.com/portfolio* (no problem, because archive-portfolio.php template is used)

The menus & pages are hierarchycal. So i created *atm* and *design* sub page. They result slug like this: *site.com/portfolio/design* and *site.com/portfolio/atm* . The problem is:

- if there is any portfolio detail that contains **design** or **atm** words, the sub page template detected as sigle-portfolio.php
- if there is no portfolio detail that contains that words, the sub page template detected as index.php

I've try to assign a custom page templates such as `page-templates/portfolio-category.php` to the sub page. But doesn't work. I think i should change my pages & menus to use slug other than *portfolio* .

Anyone willing to help?

Comment: Good question, I have tried it by performing same action to my wordpress. It is wordpress default functionality, the prority of post layout is preferable in comparision to page. So, as per me you just need to change the slug for any one of them. Look at here, this may help you : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-slug-priority-over-post-archive-slug?replies=4

Comment: Good idea, 
you're right @SunilChaudhary , it seems like "changing the slug" is the best solution